# Cómo hago coincidir elementos de dos listas con javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Estoy desarrollando un bot de discord con javascript.

Para un comando del bot, éste enviará respuestas aleatorias con texto e imagen. Por tanto, le puse dos variables: una con texto y otra con imagen. Cada una de estas dos variables tienen varios elementos, como una lista:

```
var txt: (t1, t2,...)
var img: (i1, i2,...)
```

Entonces, necesito que al ejecutar el comando, el bot envie un mensaje con textos e imagen que coincidan, es decir, texto1 con imagen1, texto2 con imagen2, etc.

Éste es mi código:

```
  var txt = ["texto1", "texto2"]
  var Random = Math.floor(Math.random() * txt.length);
  
  var img = [imagen1, imagen2]
  var aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length);

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix +"meme")){
    message.channel.send(txt[Random], img[aleatorio]);
  }});
```

Comment: Los arreglos están ordenados?

Comment: A qué te refieres?

Comment: ¿Y no sería mejor usar un único número aleatorio y utilizarlo para leer los índices de los arreglos? De ese modo `array_texto[random+1]` y `array_imagen[random+1]` puntaría siempre al mismo número de índice, p.e. el elemento 2 de cada uno de los arreglos si random=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Por qué no crear parejas en un único array?

```
const list = [
  { txt: "algo", img: ...}
  { txt: "algo mas ", img: ...}
];
```

De este modo sólo necesitas un valor aleatorio para obtener ambos valores:

```
message.channel.send(list[aleatorio].txt, list[aleatorio].img);
```